# Nested if statements in while loop

Tags: python

```
mean = "Test"

while mean.isalpha():
    mean = input("Please enter the Mean (Value must be between minus infinity (–∞) and plus infinity (+∞)): ")
    if mean == "":
        mean = 0
        break
    elif mean.isdigit():
        mean = float(mean)
        if mean <= 0:
            print("Error")

print(mean)
```

Could someone kindly explain to me why does my if statement in the elif loop not work? Also, why do I need a break in my first if statement.

Comment: ```mean``` will only be empty when you press "Enter" when it prompts for input. And ```break```  is kind of ... optional. Here, it is just that the value was not entered. And the program was designed that an empty string is invalid. So it breaks

Comment: Hi Sujay, if i remove the break statement in my first if loops it shows the error 'int' object has no attribute 'isalpha' when i try to run the code.

Comment: Just a minute, I will post an asnwer

Comment: @TiaKangJun Basically, that's because you're treating `mean` as a string in lines 1 and 4, but treating it as a float in line 9. Since you're accessing a string attribute inside the loop, if `mean` is a float, this will fail.

Comment: @TiaKangJun, Can you please explain what do you want to achieve by this program?

Comment: @SumitKumar the question that im trying to solve is this. Employ a Python program to ask the user to enter the mean and variance of the distribution. Tell the user that the mean can be any value between minus infinity (–∞) and plus infinity (+∞), but the variance must be a value larger than 0. Integrate certain control mechanism to ensure that the variance condition is fulfilled, and the input is numeric. If the user press ENTER without providing any values, the program will automatically set μ to 0 and σ2 to 1.

Answer (score 1):

The *break* exits the *while* loop.

The *elif* block is unnecessary and has no effect.  The code block in the *elif* section can be unindented.

Answer (score 1):

When prompted for an input, if you simply press <kbd>Enter</kbd> without entering any value, then the returned value is an empty string: `""`.

The program is designed to catch that empty string. If you enter something, the string is not empty. So `mean==""` is False. So it goes to the `elif` statement.

```
mean = 0
break
```

If you don't put this `break`, it will raise an error. This is because an integer or float doesn't have an attribute called `.alpha`. Once `break` is encountered, it exits the loop

Also, you are converting `mean`'s datatype to floating point or integer. So it will raise an error.

```
mean = "Test"

while mean.isalpha():
    mean = input("Please enter the Mean (Value must be between minus infinity (–∞) and plus infinity (+∞)): ")
    if mean == "":
        mean = 0
        break
    elif mean.isdigit():
        mean = float(mean)
        if mean <= 0:
            print("Error")

print(mean)
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation sujay. However, i thought that if the variable is an int or float, then mean.isalpha = False. Thus shouldn't it break out of the while loop

Comment: I was thinking that the conversion should be only temporary, i.e. changing `if mean <= 0` to `if float(mean) <= 0`.

Comment: `.isalpha` only works on strings. A `float` or an `int` can't contain letters so if you know the variable is a `float` or an `int` such a check is pointless.

Answer (score 0):

Because the sign "-" is not a digit. So when you do `.isdigit()` in your `elif` on something with "-", it will give you `False` and won't reach the nested if.

To fix it you can change the `elif` to:

```
elif mean.isdigit() or ((len(mean) > 1) and (mean[0] == '-') and mean[1:].isdigit()):
```

To take into account negative numbers.

Or even better, use `try` and `except` on conversion to `float` to see if it's a valid number.

Comment: Hi Aryerez, if that is the case how do I fix this?

Comment: @TiaKangJun Added fixes

Comment: thank so much for the help. that helped me solved the problem I had! if you don't mind, would mind showing me how the try and except statement will help me here?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing one `break` in `elif` block.

```
elif mean.isdigit():
        mean = float(mean)
        if mean <= 0:
            print("Error")
        break
```

in here, you are making `mean`  as float, and `isalpha()` is a string funtion. If you dont break the loop, it'll  move to next iteration and `while mean.isalpha():` will  give error  as `mean` has changed to  float

Comment: The code runs just fine if i do it like this though. 

mean = "Test"

while mean.isalpha():
    mean = input("Please enter the Mean (Value must be between minus infinity (–∞) and plus infinity (+∞)): ")
    if mean == "":
        mean = 0
        break
    elif mean.isdigit():
        mean = float(mean)

print(mean)

Comment: @TiaKangJun try  with `34` as input, or any other number

Comment: thanks so much for letting me know my mistakes. i just tried it and it indeed shows an error if I enter any other number!

Answer (score 0):

Take following as your answer
for mean

```
while True:
    mean = input("Please enter the Mean (Value must be between minus infinity (–∞) and plus infinity (+∞)): ")
    if mean == "":
        mean = 0
        break
    elif mean.isdigit():
        mean = float(mean)
        break
    else:
        print("error")
            
print(mean)
```

for variance

```
while True:
    variance = input("Please enter the variance (Value must be greater than 0): ")
    if variance == "":
        variance = 1
        break
    elif variance.isdigit():
        variance = float(variance)
        if variance <= 0:
            print("Error")
        else:
            break
    else:
        print("error")
            
print(variance)
```